# How to retrieve RSocket Data to different tabs?

Tags: vue.js, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, rsocket

This is my code, it works only for the tab I am on. I receive a response and everything seems to be working fine, I still do not understand the operation of the technology in its entirety, that is why I go to you.

It ends in the "responseHanlder"

```js
connect() {
    // backend ws endpoint
    const wsURL = "ws://localhost:6565/rsocket";

    // rsocket client
    const client = new RSocketClient({
      serializers: {
        data: JsonSerializer,
        metadata: IdentitySerializer,
      },
      setup: {
        keepAlive: 60000,
        lifetime: 180000,
        dataMimeType: "application/json",
        metadataMimeType: "message/x.rsocket.routing.v0",
      },
      transport: new RSocketWebSocketClient({
        url: wsURL,
      }),
    });
    
    client.connect()
          .then((sock) => {
               document.getElementById("connect")
                       .addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                          numberRequester(sock);
                       });
          }, errorHanlder);

    /*Aquí comienza el código del primer socket para insertar un producto
    antes de enviar la notificación primero realiza una acción*/
    const numberRequester = (socket) => {
    
            socket
                .requestResponse({
                  data: {
                    id: null,
                    subscriber: retrieveData.id,
                    titulo: "Se insertó un nuevo producto",
                    descripcion:
                    "Aquí se agrega una descripcion breve de lo que se acaba de hacer (opcional)",
                    fecha_inicio: today,
                    fecha_final: final,
                    leido: false,
                  },
                  metadata:
                    String.fromCharCode("insert.notification".length) +
                    "insert.notification",
                })
                .subscribe({
                  onComplete: responseHanlder,
                  onError: errorHanlder,
                  onNext: responseHanlder,
                  onSubscribe: (subscription) => {
                    //subscription.request(100); // set it to some max value
                  },
                });
            }


    // error handler
    const errorHanlder = (e) => console.log(e);
    // response handler
    const responseHanlder = (payload) => {
      this.sendNotification(payload.data);
    };
}
```

After sending the data, my rsocket receives the information and in turn, I receive a response with the data I need. For now, it works only in the tab that runs it, but I need that information reflected in the other tabs because it is a prototype of notifications.

Comment: With "other tabs" you mean tabs of your browser?

Comment: Different tabs ... Well, they would rather be different users in different sessions or browsers, I don't know if I explain myself. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I think I understand, you mean different clients.

Comment: Yes, thanks, because I have a response and it works in the client that executes requestResponse, but it does not reflect it to me in the other clients. I do not know if there is a solution to this, I think it should, because it is like working with sockets, right?

Comment: I believe the browser tabs will be separate for security reasons.  I suspect the best way to implement this is by the server broadcasting to all connections for the same user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## RSocket is statefull, session-oriented, application protocol

That means, that every time your RSocket client connects to the server, it opens a connection and communicates with your server over it.

In the case of the client is a Browser, your connection will not be accessible to other browser sessions for security reasons.

## How to broadcast messages via rsocket

Actually, in the case of browser, you can use 2 options:

### Broker kind of messaging

You can always connect to a single mediator server which will ensure your messages are broadcast to all the destinations.

You may find such an example of application at [Spring Tutorials](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-webflux-kotlin-rsocket/)

### Broker less messaging with WebRTC transport (experimental and not officially released)

We have a couple of experiments on bringing WebRTC (along with normal WebSocket) transport to the browser communication.

Please find those experiments [here](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/experimental/webrtc/packages/rsocket-examples/src/WebRTCTransportExample.js). Please try it and share your feedback/vote on for this transport support at our issue tracker if you see the need for the one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it is the solution I need. I've been going through the code and from what you mention I'm sure it has. I just don't know how to transport it from Kotlin to Java and something about TypeScript.

I really appreciate the support and the time spent, I strive to get to understand it.